# Replacing Array Inside a State Object with a Different Length - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, nested, state, immutability

I have a dropdown of the US States, and when a value is selected, the `handleSelectState` function is called, which first calls another function to get an array of counties for that US state and then sets the `selectedStateCode` to the target value and `availableCounties` to the new array in the `geoForm` state object.

I am confused about how to update the state of the `availableCounties` array. I understand that the `availableCounties` array is a nested inside the `geoForm` object, and therefore I can't mutate the array by directly assigning it like below.

```
const [geoForm, setGeoForm] = useState({

    selectedStateCode: '',

    availableCounties: [], 
});

function handleSelectState(e) {
    const newCounties = searchCounties(e.target.value); // Array of counties for the selected state

    setGeoForm({
      ...geoForm,
      selectedStateCode: e.target.value,
      availableCounties: newCounties // Incorrect
    });
}
```

I know that I need to use an immutable array method here. However, I am unsure that using the `map` method will work in this scenario because from my understanding of `map`, it only loops over each item in an array, but in this scenario, `newCounties` could have a different length than `availableCounties`, and therefore you couldn't copy over `newCounties` to `availableCounties` with `map` if they are of different length.

Am I understanding the `map` method wrong? Or is there another array method to use in this case?

Comment: What do you do in your `searchCounties`? What do you mean by incorrect? Is it still the previous value?

Comment: What is the type of `newCounties` content? is it an array of strings, array of objects? You need not even spread `geoForm` inside of `setGeoForm`. It should set the value to `availableCounties` without it.

Comment: ```searchCounties``` is just a helper function to make an API call that gets the counties for the particular US State selected. It returns an array of those counties as strings for the selected state. I am pretty sure that the ```availableCounties: newCounties``` assignment is mutating the state of the nested array, and therefore is incorrect and causes the application to crash.